# is it ok to use plinq ForAll for a bulk insert into database?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, plinq

I'm doing like this:

```
 entities.AsParallel().ForAll(o => repository.Insert(o));
```

is this good, am I going to have more performance with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

This one can be faster, as it leverages the paralellism to the SQL, but in the end the SQL has to make a lock for the table (page), as it makes an insert. 
therefore each paralell request is executed after another again.

If you want to make a bulk insert, than make a SP accepting all entries (e.g. a table with SQL 2008.) or do it with Linq2SQL.

that would be the correct design solution.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not. Each insert would actually take place on a seperate thread, while bulk insert work well by transferring large amounts of data from a single thread, at a single time.

PS: SqlBulkCopy would work much, much better than a parallel insert. Use that if possible.