# Can this LinQ statement made run multi threading - using more cpu cores

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

I have written the below linq statement. But it takes huge time to process since there are so many lines. My cpu has 8 cores but only using 1 core due to running single thread.

So i wonder by any chance can this final stament run in multi threading ?

```
        List<string> lstAllLines = File.ReadAllLines("AllLines.txt").ToList();
        List<string> lstBannedWords = File.ReadAllLines("allBaddWords.txt").
Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant()).
Distinct().ToList();
```

I am asking the one below. Can that line work multi threading ?

```
        List<string> lstFoundBannedWords = lstBannedWords.Where(s => lstAllLines.
SelectMany(ls => ls.ToLowerInvariant().Split(' ')).
Contains(s)).
        Distinct().ToList();
```

C# 5 , netframework 4.5

Comment: Looked into [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)? Note, this is in no way guaranteed to make anything run faster.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth haven't checked yet but let me take a look :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582591/how-to-plinq-an-existing-linq-query-with-joins ([Understanding Speedup in PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399.aspx)) The more expensive a query is, the better candidate it is for PLINQ.

Comment: Wow it started using 5 cores with just adding 1 keyword hehe :D i love C# ^^

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: What keyword was that? I'm not too familiar with PLINQ...

Comment: @Chris `.AsParallel()` I think.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth is right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet can perform that operation using the [**Parallel Tasks Library's**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) `Parallel.ForEach` method. The snippet below takes each line in the 'all-lines' file you have, splits it on spaces, and then searches each line for banned words. The Parallel-ForEach should use all available core's on your machine's processor. Hope this helps.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(
    lstAllLines,
    line =>
    {
        var wordsInLine = line.ToLowerInvariant().Split(' ');
        var bannedWords = lstBannedWords.All(bannedWord => wordsInLine.Contains(bannedWord));
        // TODO: Add the banned word(s) in the line to a master list of banned words found.
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are rooms for performance improvements before resorting to `AsParallel`

```
HashSet<string> lstAllLines = new HashSet<string>(
                                File.ReadAllLines("AllLines.txt")
                                    .SelectMany(ls => ls.ToLowerInvariant().Split(' ')));

List<string> lstBannedWords = File.ReadAllLines("allBaddWords.txt")
                                    .Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant())
                                    .Distinct().ToList();

List<string> lstFoundBannedWords = lstBannedWords.Where(s => lstAllLines.Contains(s))
                                    .Distinct().ToList();
```

Since access to HasSet is `O(1)` and `lstBannedWords` is the shorter list, You may even not need any parallelism (`TotalSearchTime=lstBannedWords.Count*O(1)`). Lastly, you always have the option `AsParallel`

Comment: It wasn't me but you might want to rename the `lstAllLines` variable to something like `hashAllWords` to make the code easier to understand.

Comment: @Dirk I just wanted to preserve the variable names for the OP. Afterall, it is just Refactor/Rename when using VS.

Comment: actually this is not exactly doing what i am doing :) also i did not down vote. i am checking based on word by word level, you are checking literal level.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Have you tested it before commenting?